# find out if cursor had been set in ncurses.h

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I'm creating a wrapper for menu.h and want to ensure that when a menu is displayed, the cursor is turned off, however I don't want to just do a

```
curs_set(0);
```

and potentially screw up some other ui that depends on a certain cursor setting...

**TLDR**: is there any way to find out the current setting of curs_set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-curs_set):

> The  **`curs_set`**  routine  sets  the cursor state to invisible, normal, or
> very visible for visibility equal to 0, 1, or 2 respectively.   ***If  the
> terminal  supports  the visibility requested, the previous cursor state
> is returned***; otherwise, **`ERR`** is returned.